# Why wont this texture render?

Tags: rendering

[image: afterer render photo] So I created a bear mainly out of a single plain, and added different materials to different faces and uv mapped it. the stomach of the bear had a different texture then the other body. When I rendered it, the stomach texture wasn't there! the first picture shows after rendering.

Comment: The second image does not show up

Comment: I cant add it because I don't have any reputation. t

Comment: It had a white stomach texture and eye texture besides the black in the images.